# Why does the behaviour of these seemingly the same code snippets differ? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was writing a sudoku solver, and came across this weird behavior. If I do the following:

```
r = range(1,len(board)+1)
b = block(board,x,y)
nums = [x for x in r if x not in b]
```

`nums` will be different from this way of calculating it:

```
nums = [x for x in range(1,len(board)+1) if x not in block(board,x,y)]
```

The `block` is simply as follows:

```
return sum([col[y*N(board):(y+1)*N(board)] 
            for col in board[x*N(board):(x+1)*N(board)]],
            [])
```

Where `N` is just the square-root of the size of the board, and board is just a list of lists of numbers. (The reason for things like `N` and `len` all over the place is that it should work for boards that aren't 9x9 too)

My question is simply: Why could these things be different? It's just reading values and storing them in variables, not assigning anything to board itself, so why would it matter if I do `b = a` and then use `a`, or just use `b` to begin with?

Comment: What is `x` in the first case? You're overriding whatever it is with your list comprehension variable `x` in the second case at the very least.

Comment: I assume that your `block` function returns sth. different in each call in the second version based on the changing of `x` where `b` stays always the same in the first.

Comment: What they said. Note that the 2nd version needlessly recomputes `block(board,x,y)` `len(board)` times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, `b` is calculated to be `block(board,x,y)`, using whatever value `x` has at that moment. This value is then reused for all the iterations of the following list comprehension.

In the second example, `x` changes throughout the list comprehension, so with each iteration, `block(board,x,y)` will return a different result.

Comment: I'm asking myself how I could overlook this, it's so obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you use

```
r = range(1,len(board)+1)
b = block(board,x,y)
nums = [x for x in r if x not in b]
```

`x` is most likely already set to some constant, hence `b` becomes constant in your list comprehension. When you use your second list comprehension, `x` has a different value (iterating over `r`) throughout the comprehension, and overrides whatever `x` is on your function or module level - hence every check if `x` is in `block(board,x,y)` becomes dependent on your comprehension iteration.

Give your list comprehension variable a different name than `x`, and be careful about overwriting variable names.

---

Here's a minimal example where you can see that the variable name `x` is overwritten, and how it affects each call to your function.

```
>>> r = range(5)
>>> x = 1
>>> b = range(x+1)
>>> [x for x in r if x not in b]
[2, 3, 4]
>>> [x for x in range(5) if x not in range(x+1)]
[]
```